# How to get Ubuntu Server plus Domain running with uwsgi nginx? (from scratch)

Tags: django, apache, nginx, uwsgi, ubuntu-server

This is my first post so I apologize if it isn't up with stack overflow standards.

I just purchased a dedicated vps server at nfoservers.com.
I have two ip's on my server which is running ubuntu 16.04-LTS x64.
I have never set up a server from scratch.
My biggest issue is getting my domain to point to the server IP.

- I have the name server set to ns1.nfoservers.com & ns2.nfoservers.com.
- I also have apache2 installed and my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.com.conf and /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.com.conf look like so:
  https://pastebin.com/nd7eMH9H

  ServerName domain.com
      ServerAlias www.domain.com

  ```
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com/public_html

  ErrorLog /var/www/html/domain.com/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/domain.com/logs/access.log combined

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  ```

I do not have nginx set up yet but I didn't think my problem was nginx because from my understanding apache can serve the site to and ip or domain. Lastly I might add that my goal is to clone my django web app to the server once I can get my domain working... Please Help I am desperate.

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to use both Apache and nginx; they are usually alternatives.

Comment: Well I guess I don't know which to use.  This comment didn't really answer my question. Do you have an answer that will point me in the right direction